# Android studio path error in Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am getting this error when I open Android Studio:

> System path '/Users/username/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.1' is
>   invalid. If you have modified the 'idea.system.path' property please
>   make sure it is correct, otherwise please re-install the IDE.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems that the easiest solution is to re-install Android Studio. I personally recommend v.2.2 which is formally still beta, but it is quite mature and brings tons of important enhancements.

Comment: In my case, re-install did not work.  What DID work was to make sure the owner on .../Library/Caches itself was set not to "root:staff", which it had somehow been set to, but to "username:staff" - where username was correct for that user on that machine.

Answer (score 16):

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

- Open your "Applications" folder
- Right click on Android Studio then choose "Show Package Contents"
- Navigate to the "bin" folder
- Open the "idea.properties" file with a text edit tool and add this property to the bottom of the file:

  > idea.system.path='/Users/MacName/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio3.1'

  then save the file.

Run Android Studio again and it should work.

Comment: Do you know why after every restart OSX I have to do this step for Studio 3?

Comment: @user2988832, You may need to check that file/directory permissions using the `ls` and `chmod` commands. Sometimes its an OS issue that changes this file/directory's permission. This could happen after updating Android Studio as well. Just a double check on the directory permission.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed on my mac like this instead and it works:

Open your "Applications" folder
Right click on Android Studio then choose "Show Package Contents"
Navigate to the "bin" folder
Open the "idea.properties" file with a text edit tool and add this property to the bottom of the file:
idea.log.path=/Users/macUser/Library/Cache/AndroidStudio3.1

then save the file.

Run Android Studio again and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

just check the folder permission in , Replace "xxx" with username

```
/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Google
```

It needs read/Write/Execute Permission.
Will have to run `sudo chmod 777 .` to fix and relaunch the Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the root cause (at least for me) and I don't love sudo editing files and folders so here's what worked for me. Turns out Chrome was creating the Application Support folder with root permissions. Android Studio uses that same folder but couldn't do anything with it. Essentially the fix was:

- Delete the `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google` folder (may have to use sudo here )
- Open Android Studio (this creates the support folder again with user permissions)
- Open Chrome (your temporary settings may be deleted but it shouldn't matter with sync turned on)